# Check if startdate is greater then enddate

Tags: navision, dynamics-nav, microsoft-dynamics-nav

I want to compare two dates. I triied like this:

```
SetDates(Rec, StartDate2, EndDate2, Regelkorting);

BOMB.RESET;
BOMB.SETRANGE(StartDate2,StartDate2);
IF BOMB.FINDFIRST THEN BEGIN
IF BOMB.StartDate2 > BOMB.EndDate2 THEN BEGIN
ERROR('startdatum kan niet groter zijn dan einddatum');
END;
END
```

But there is no message showing

and this is the output:

BOM Component
530120,10000,Artikel,530120,Intergas 041107 HREco 24 CW3,ST,0,,,,,0,,0,,01-10-16,10-10-13,0,Nee,Nee,

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comparation it's ok, but I think you are not finding the correct record of BOMB.

You have this:

```
BOMB.RESET;
BOMB.SETRANGE(StartDate2,StartDate2);
IF BOMB.FINDFIRST THEN BEGIN
  IF BOMB.StartDate2 > BOMB.EndDate2 THEN BEGIN
    ERROR('startdatum kan niet groter zijn dan einddatum');
  END;
END;
```

You filter only by `StartDate2` field and not for the **primary key**, so you find the wrong record.

So Filter BOMB Table for the fields of **primary key**, Standard **BOM Component** table have this primary key `Parent Item No.,Line No.` if you didn't change this try this:

```
BOMB.RESET;
BOMB.SETRANGE("Parent Item No.", "Parent Item No.");
BOMB.SETRANGE("Line No.", "Line No.");
IF BOMB.FINDFIRST THEN BEGIN
  IF BOMB.StartDate2 > BOMB.EndDate2 THEN BEGIN
    ERROR('startdatum kan niet groter zijn dan einddatum');
  END;
END;
```